# LibreOffice Calc how to fill blank cells with value of last known cell that is not empty

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a csv file opened in Calc, in `Column1`, the last cell with value is on row `8333`, start from `8334` onwards to the bottom of the file, the cells are all empty; I am wondering how to fill these empty cells with the value of `Column1` on row `8333`; even better is it possible that I can fill these blank cells with randomly selected values from rows (`2` - `8333`) for  `Column1`. All the headers are on row `1`.

Since the file has about 74k rows, so mouse clicking is tedious, is it possible to automatically select blank cells starting from `8334` to `74503`?

Comment: Select the first cell then `CTRL` `SHIFT` `arrow down` ? To fill with random values you could use `=RAND()` or `=RANDBETWEEN()` (copy the formula first, then selct and paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in cell `A8334` (the first column is known as column A):

```
=INDIRECT("A" & RANDBETWEEN(2;8333))
```

Then do the following:

- Select cell `A74503` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill the formula down. This may take a few seconds.

Documentation: [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT)